# the stackTraceElement shows error in a function does not exist in my code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, stack-trace

i created my own way to send all errors to the firebase realtime database, i send the activity name, function name, error message, error line number. but sometimes the stackTraceElement
send something like that "[myPackageName].MainActivity.B(Unknown Source:11)"

1. package name
2. activityName = MainActivity
3. function name = B (i dont have any function called B in all activities and classes)
4. error line number = 11 (on the line code 11, there is just an import of a static variable)

i wrote all function's code within try and catch
ex:

```
private void function_1(){
try{
//some code
}catch (Exception e) {
            //getting the function name
            String functionName = Objects.requireNonNull(new Object() {
            }.getClass().getEnclosingMethod()).getName();
            
            //getting the stackTraceElement that contains my acticityName
            String stackTraceElement = "";
            for (StackTraceElement ste : e.getStackTrace()) {
                if (ste.getClassName().contains(activityName)) {
                    stackTraceElement = ste.toString();
                    break;
                }
            }
            // getting the error message
            String msg = e.getMessage();
            //send all data to firebase through external class
            fireBase_class.sendError(context, activityName, stackTraceElement, msg, functionName);
        }
  }
}
```

where the function B comes from?  Note: some time i got function called M, N, L, A .....

also, if anyone have a better idea to send the errors please share it :D

Comment: Most likely those are runtime exceptions generated from calls to library functions.

Comment: @hfontanez, do they crashes the app? and is there anyway to catch the "app crashing"?

Comment: Are you using Lambda functions?

Comment: @hfontanez, yes, only on click listeners, call back functions ..... , where android studio suggests me to use it, but not in my own created functions

Comment: I think that's the culprit. I think those Lambda function generate intermediate objects to perform their functions and most likely one of them is throwing a runtime exception. To your question, yes... they can crash your app. You can catch the exceptions. BUT, you might not be able to recover from them gracefully. You need to focus on removing the error rather than looking for ways to handle it.

Comment: Removing the error might be coding your method slightly different. I suggest you google how to fix the exception you are getting.

Comment: Are you perhaps using ProGuard or another code obfuscator?

Comment: @RobSpoor, no i don't, depends on hfontanez answer, i will replace all lambda functions with regular functions, then i will see what will happened later on :)